# How to detect class names from html in css files in VS Code?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to switch over from WebStorm to VS Code, but this problem is troubling me. In WebStrom, if a css file is linked in html, class names can be detected from html as show in the pic below, but this feature is not supported in VS Code. Is there any extension in vscode that can add this feature for vscode and solve this problem? thanks!

[webstorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQudO.png)
[vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvcR9.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good extension for this [HTML to CSS autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=solnurkarim.html-to-css-autocompletion)

Answer (score 0):

This extension can solve your problem. As far as I am concerned, it is not supported natively.
[IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion)

Comment: I've tried this extension before but won't work, it  can detect class name from css to html, but can't do the reverse, thanks anyway!